# svn -- Time since last merge

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I am in need of a "time since last merge" report. We have a single branch where changes from other branches are integrated. To keep everyone in sync, we encourage branch masters to perform a merge from integration line to their respective branches.

I am working on a post-commit hook that will send a report every time a commit is done on integration line that explains:

1. source branch
2. time since last merge between integration and other branches

svn mergeinfo is the starting point, but what other commands will help me get this info?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

svn log gives you the figure semi-straight.

If all merging is done on the highest possible directory level (as is best practice), then execute the following command:

```
svn log -g https://myrepos.tld/branches/single-private-feature-branch
```

you will get the usualy history plus revisions that were merged into this branch. Look for the string "Merged via: ". The first hit will be the last merge into this branch. You can optionally fetch the log entry of the revision given to make sure it is comming from the integration branch and was not merged from some other place.

All this can be done with simple shellscripting.

Hope it helps :)

C

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools available to do SVN reporting. Many of them are mentioned in the answer to this question: [What reporting is available for svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466572/what-reporting-is-available-for-svn)